# Firebase database ref on not updating at first

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I'm building a chat app with react native and firebase.
When the user sign in, previous messages have to load at first launch but it provides empty arrays to promise at first then when I connect again, it shows up...
I'm using snack and I have to change code to see the chat histroy(In order to update the device).
How can I load at first launch?

edit:
firebase structure

```
userName:
-rooms:
  -otherUser:
     -messages
     -name
```

Code:

```
firebase.database().ref(`userName/rooms`).on('child_added', snapshot => callback(parse(snapshot)));;
const parse = snapshot => {
    //console.log(snapshot);
    const { name } = snapshot.val();
    const { key: _id } = snapshot;
    const rooms = {
      _id,
      name
    };
    return rooms;
  };
```

And this is happening in my useEffect:

```
const loadRequiredMaterials = async () => {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        //var loadedRooms = [...rooms]
        var loadedRooms = []
          await on(oldRooms => {
            loadedRooms = [oldRooms, ...loadedRooms]
          });
        await resolve([loadedRooms]);
      })
    }
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser)
      loadRequiredMaterials()
      .then((result)=> {
        console.log(result)
        setRooms(result[0]);
      })

    }
```

Comment: Please, provide us with at least part of your code and firebase data structure.

Comment: I've updated the code @ArtemArkhipov